# How to include a link in your email to your attached csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I want to include a link at the bottom of the email that a user can click and the attached csv will automatically be downloaded. Something like this:

> Best,
> Nick
>
> - orders.csv

In my mailer I have this:

```rb
def order_summary_sent(params)
    attachments.inline["orders.csv"] = { mime_type: "text/csv", content: params[:csv_content] }
    mail(subject: "Order summary", to: params["recipient"])
```

The file is successfully shown as an attachment but what `erb` code should I write to also include it directly in the email body?

I tried the following:

```
      <%= link_to "orders.csv", attachments["orders.csv"].url %>
```

However, when I click on the link I get `cid:635a746039b8b_213558301d83608a@nick.mail`

Comment: The attachment is already part of the email. Why do you want to download it? Download from where, the server or your email client?

Comment: It's part of the email but I would also like to include it directly in the email body. It would be downloaded from the email client